# Why the name of my <a> is not changing with the for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I'm working with `django` and I need to create dynamically some links `<a>`. My code is,

```
{% for node in Last_val_nodes %}
    <a href="#" class="nodeInfo" name="{{node.0}}">{{node.0}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

The links showed are ok, if for example I have a list of 3 nodes like, ['Node X','Node A','Node P'] I can see the three perfectly.

But now I want to know what link has been clicked. For this I'm using `jquery`,

```
$('.nodeInfo').click(function(){
    var name = $('.nodeInfo').attr("name");
    alert(name);
});
```

But when I click it always alert the first node name, in this case "Node X". Why is not writing a different `name` for every one? How can I know the link clicked if it is created dynamically?

Thank you

Comment: Use **$(this).attr(“name”)**

Comment: Ok, it's working. Why with the class is not working? If you write it as answer I close the question :)

Comment: Someone has already written the answer, but: **$('.nodeInfo')** refers to the object jQuery selects. jQuery always selects the first item that matches a selector (OK, not always, but most of the cases), and it's always going to be the SAME DOM element - no matter where you clicked. **this** refers to the object being clicked (in this case), so it's not always the first DOM element of a selected collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django isn't at fault here at all. Inside your event handler, `$('.nodeInfo')` selects a collection of all elements with the CSS class `nodeInfo`, regardless of which element actually received the click event; the `.attr` method picks the first of these and returns the value of its `name` attribute. Instead you should write

```
$('.nodeInfo').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    alert(name);
});
```

This will pick the correct element. In fact, you can even dispense with jQuery here and just write `this.name` instead of `$(this).attr("name")`. (This may fail to be directly applicable to other attributes.)

(Also remember *not* to use a fat-arrow function as the event handler, as those inherit `this` from their surrounding scope.)